# Achieve nested for loops using recursion PHP

Tags: php, recursion, nested-loops

```
<?php

for( $t=0;$t<=9;$t++ ){
    for( $o=0;$o<=9;$o++ ){
        for( $g=0;$g<=9;$g++ ){
            echo $t.$o.$g."<br />"; 
        }
    }
}


?>
```

This program gives an output of :

000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
013
014
015
016
017
018
019
020
021
022
023
024
025
026
027
028
029
030
031
032
033
034
035
036
037
038
039
040
041
042
043
044
045
046
047
048
049
050
051
052
053
054
055
056
057
058
059
060
061
062
063
064
065
TILL 999

I want to acheive such a thing using recursion ..say i want to do the same for four nested loops :
I have written a program for this but in vain :

```
<?php

$done = array("t","o","g");
$i = 0;

function recurse($x){
    //$done = array("t","o","g");
    global $done;
    global $i;
    global $t;
    global $o;
    global $g;

    $i++;

        for( $$x=0;$$x<=9;$$x++ ){
            if( $x!="g" ){
                recurse($done[$i]);
            }else{
                echo $t.$o.$g."<br />";
                $i=0;

            } //if else 

        } // for end



} //function end

echo "{$done[0]} {$done[1]} {$done[2]}<br />";
 recurse($done[0]);

    print_r($done);


?>
```

OUTPUT :
t o g
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009

So instead of 010 011 012 after 009 its going back to 000 .
Help appreciated!

Comment: Just for the record, I don't understand why the question was closed as unclear. It contains code, the result and the expected result, just as it should be. Only because the code is horrible in its very approach doesn't make the question wrong. For the record, you need to decrement $i when leaving, otherwise the calling function will use the wrong element from $done. That's the reason why people avoid globals and why Georg's answer provides a much better approach, i.e. by passing all relevant state as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
function enum($n) {
    if($n == 0)
        return array('');
    $result = array();
    foreach(enum($n - 1) as $e)
        foreach(range(0, 9) as $k)
            $result []= $e . $k;
    return $result;
}

print_r(enum(3));
```